# Identifying which button was clicked using php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, css

I'm making a small site for a production company where when the user clicks on a director's name from my menu, all menu items disappear and all that's displayed is the biography and work produced by that director.

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to pass the javascript variable in charge of identifying which director was clicked on to php so that it can actually retrieve the director's information from the database... Is there a way to do this without GET or POST, as I am trying to maintain it in a single seamless animation from page-to-page?

To clarify, I would want to contain all of this in a single page, without any interstitial pages

Answer (score 2):

You should use AJAX to achieve this. While you'd still be technically passing GET or POST variables, it would be seamless.

Answer (score 1):

There are likely various script based solutions, but it can be done without script.

Use a form with multiple submit buttons. Give each a unique name, only the one that is clicked will be submitted with the form.

You can also load all information for each director into the page and just display the information for the one that was clicked on, no need for a separate call to the server.

Alternatively you can use an AJAX request. Use a unique identifier from the clicked button (e.g. its name, id or class) in the request so that appropriate information is returned. But such functionality is more work and much more prone to error than a plain form or just showing or hiding elements that are already in the page.

Comment: Yeah, I considered AJAX but last time I did my inexperience resulted in a pretty messy jumble of code... I also considered loading all of them at once but I was concerned about loading times for visitors. It may be the best solution in this case, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think what RobG suggested about loading all of the data at once and then using JavaScript to hide/show what you want is the way to go in this case.

Let's say you had 3 directors, and you gave them each a 'div' containing their bio and work, and each div had an id='dir1', 'dir2', and 'dir3'. They all have a class named 'directorInfo' and they are hidden when the page first loads using the attribute style='display:none'. There would be three buttons that correspond to each director named 'but1', 'but2', 'but3', which would each have a value=1, 2, or 3, and I would also give each of them a class='directorButtons' so that they are easier to identify with your JQuery.

With your JQ, bind the buttons to a click event. like so:
 
 
    `$('.directorButtons').on('click', function(){ 

    $('.directorInfo').hide(); 
 
    $('#menuItems').hide(); 
 
    $('#dir'+this.val()).show(); 
 
     return false; 
 
    }); 
 
    $('.close').on("click", function(){ 
 
    //give the user a way to unhide the menu. 
 
    $('.directorInfo').hide(); 
 
    $('#menuItems').show(); 
 
    return false; 
 
    });`

The second part of code is because each div should also have a close button, or an X inside an 'a' tag with href='#' and class='close', so that when the user clicks the X they will be taken back to the start and the menu will be visible again.

This is a simple example that you could tweak to do a lot (like using modals and animations). Doing it this way rather than with AJAX also gives the added benefit of responding instantly rather than waiting for a response from the server.